# drag and drop библиотека formstone upload

Tags: jquery, drag-n-drop

Делаю на сайте загрузку путем перетаскивания, но столкнулся с проблемой. Скрипт отрабатывает нормально, файлы загружаются как надо. 
На сервере я принимаю картинки и обрезаю их, но как обрезать картинки я задаю эти параметры перед отправкой.

В переменные я получаю из input необходимые данные, и передаю их через postData. Вот тут и возникает проблема, значения в переменные передаются те, которые были там указаны по умолчанию при загрузке странице. Пытаюсь перезаписать переменные при улавливании изменений через $('.filtr').on('change', function () {console.log('change')}); Но это не помогает.

Как мне получить данные из input именно в тот момент как я собираюсь загрузить картинку?

```
    $('.filtr').on('change', function () {
        var id = $('input[name="form[id]"]').val();
        var table = $('input[name="form[table]"]').val();
        var file_tip = $('input[name="file[tip]"]').val();
        var crop = $('input[name="file[crop]"]').val();
        var quality = $('input[name="file[quality]"]').val();
        var mini_crop = $('input[name="file[mini_crop]"]').val();
        var mini_quality = $('input[name="file[mini_quality]"]').val();
        console.log('change')
    });

    var id = $('input[name="form[id]"]').val();
    var table = $('input[name="form[table]"]').val();
    var file_tip = $('input[name="file[tip]"]').val();
    var crop = $('input[name="file[crop]"]').val();
    var quality = $('input[name="file[quality]"]').val();
    var mini_crop = $('input[name="file[mini_crop]"]').val();
    var mini_quality = $('input[name="file[mini_quality]"]').val();

    $('.upload').upload({
        action:'./',
        label:'Перетащите файлы для загрузки',
        postKey:'upload',        
        maxQueue:1,
        maxSize:10485760,
        postData:{
                upload_table: table,
                id: id,
                file_tip: file_tip,
                crop: crop,
                quality: quality,
                mini_crop: mini_crop,
                mini_quality: mini_quality
        }
    })
    .on('start.upload', Start)
    .on('filestart.upload', fileStart)
    .on('fileprogress.upload', fileProgress)
    .on('filecomplete.upload', fileComplete)
    .on('fileerror.upload', fileError)
    .on('fileerror.upload', Complete)
```

Comment: Очень прошу помочь разобраться.